# Not getting SSRS report output in desired format

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-grouping

I am designing SSRS 2005 report which has four subreports within a main report.
The report has  a group header containing  "**name**" dataset field .Each subreport is grouped on the same "**name**" field.This name field is also one of the column for the dataset of each subreport.

A rough format of the report is as shown below(For each name field of the main report dataset we have four sub reports)

[image]

I tried adding header with image as a group header of a table and subreports as table rows with all rows grouped by **name** field  but i am getting the same data in each report.
Can someone please guide me how to go about to get the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for subreports to filter the data from the parent report, you'll need to match a field from your main report (**NAME**?) with the field in your subreport using the **Subreport Properties' Parameters** tab.

You should have a Parameter in your subreport and a Filter on the subreports data that uses the parameter. This way, each record in the main report will have each subreport filtered by your grouping field.

For more info:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd239314(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: do the parameters you are mentioning need to be present in the sub report's dataset query

Comment: You don't **have** to use the **Parameters** in the Dataset query - but that's the best way for performance purposes.The parameters can be used in the **FILTER ** of the Dataset, or the FILTER of your subreport table(s). It's best to do it in the Dataset (as a FILTER or Parameter) rather than the individual tables and charts so there's only one thing to change.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the whole thing (header and subreports) in a List, and populate the List from your "Main" dataset.   Then pass values from the List's dataset to the subreports and header.